# Apache Busy worker thread increased to MaxRequestWorkers setting and getting error AH00286: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting

Tags: apache, bitbucket, web-worker, apache2.4, worker-process

In our production Apache servers i am observing error AH00286: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

My Environment:

I am using Apache Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu).
 MPM worker config as bellow.

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
  ServerLimit         25
  StartServers        2
  ThreadLimit         64
  MaxClients          150
  MinSpareThreads     25
  MaxSpareThreads     75
  ThreadsPerChild     25
  MaxRequestsPerChild 0
  ListenBacklog       511
</IfModule>
```

During this time there are concurrent request observed to the server however the HTTP response code for all requests are 200 for almost all request excluding very few 302.

I am running Bitbucket server behind reverse proxy.

Question1) how to find my ListenBacklog  that is 511 is getting filled OR how to identify its not enough?

Question2) How do i reproduce this error ( i have used AB tool in the past but seeking advice to on this)

Question3) When i get this error, will new user requests & existing user request which are in the queue will be rejected?

Question4) I have enabled monitoring of thread usage based on the scoreboard usage (/usr/sbin/apache2ctl fullstatus) numbers, it prints busy worker thread as 150 and get reset to 0 in next Min when error is observed. is Apache reset all the worker thread when it gets an  error as mentioned above?

Thanks in advance for attention on this matter.

Comment: After log observation, I got below data from splunk at the minute whare I am observing this behavior.  

150 events (3/2/20 11:02:00.000 PM to 3/2/20 11:03:00.000 PM)
128 events (3/2/20 11:03:00.000 PM to 3/2/20 11:04:00.000 PM)
 0 events     (3/2/20 11:04:00.000 PM to 3/2/20 11:05:00.000 PM)

as per theory 150 is max busy workers &  socket’s listen backlog can not exceeds that of net.core.somaxconn sysctl value that is 128. As per this theory my logs requests are exact matching... that is 150+128 and next minute Zero requests.

Comment: do I need to check tomcat web application (bitbucket) load when 150 workers are busy? did not heard anyone in past 1 week, is my articulation of apache worker usage is wrong? can someone guide here?